# my webapi mvc4 not run in server with net.4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

hello I made one applicattion(WEB API MVC4 which connect with SQL server) using framework 4.5, in my IIS express run fine but I try publish in other server which uses framework 4.0, my applicattion not run ? 
I change in properties of my application works with framework 4.0 and in my IIS express run fine but other server not run.
I can't upload version framework in the other server.
thanks for the asnwers and sorry for my english I'm learning

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have changed target framework attribute in your web application that isn't sufficient to deploy. In your codes you may use libraries that require .net 4.5 while you only have changed the setting. About running this in your iis express must say that your system by default supports .net 4.5 while your app says i need only .net 4.0. So .net 4.5 related parts will be compiled and executed on local server and no ambiguous thing is here.

Answer (score 0):

Running .NET4.5 based app on .NET4 machine is not supported. Simply because .NET4.5 is a super set of .NET4. Everything that's built for .NET4 works on .NET4.5 but not the other way around. If you are using Visual Studio 2012, you can change TargetFramework (in project properties) to .NET Framework 4, this will ensure that your app is built for .NET4.

--Varun
(.NET Framework Team)